# Cannot find symbol when using entrySet() function after import java.util.*

Tags: java, import, hashmap, entryset

I am using a function `Map.entrySet()`. When I am using `import java.util.*` it gives cannot find symbol error. But, when I am doing `import java.util.Map.Entry` it compiles. Shouldn't "*" include `Map.Entry?`

Am I missing anything?

Bottom line using import `java.util.*` gives me cannot find symbol error.
For the same code import `java.Map.Entry;` does not. Why?

Thank You.

Comment: Please show the actual code that fails to compile.

Comment: "Shouldn't "*" include Map.Entry?" I don't think so (if you use `Entry` directly you must `import j.u.Map.Entry`. Usually, `Map.Entry` is used not `Entry`)

Comment: As a side note, you should start using some IDE, they handle import for you  ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The star import is used for importing all classes of the package. When you specify

```
import java.util.*;
```

You are denoting that all classes that have full name `java.util.<ClassName>` are to be considered imported.

`java.util.Map.Entry` is an inner class of `java.util.Map` class. The star import for sub-classes will be something like this

```
import java.util.Map.*;
```

I can't say that it is a good practice to use start imports at all. Most of coding guidelines recommend to avoid it. Sub-class star imports isn't something you usually will come across in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.